# Where to find code and console to debug background.js in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

how can I debug the code that I have in my background.js which contain some of my browser action.

the code is running on the load of the tab to validate the URL

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

but when I inspect the pop up and try to debug into my code I can not find background.js in my files.

how can I debug this file ?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/10081898/2336725 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10257301/2336725?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can debug your extension's `background.js` in the **development environment** (debugger) from the Chrome Extension page at `chrome://extensions`:

It has a link to do that in each extension, often called "generated background page.html", (because Chrome generate a html page to contain your js).

If you're using Event Pages (background page with persistent:false in your manifest code), perhaps you should like to turn into persistent:true only for debug purpose.

The Event Page (i.e. persistent:false) unloads after few secondos of inactivity, and closes its debug window.  persistent:true changes this, the page doesn't unload.  It's better for debug, but turn into persistent:false when you get the debug done, because it's more efficient.